# Does "alquanto" express a greater quantity than "parecchio"?

Tags: word-choice

> Si tratta di oggetti **alquanto** strani.

> Si tratta di oggetti **parecchio** strani.

Does *alquanto* refer to a less, equal or greater quantity in comparison to *parecchio*?

Are the objects in the first sentence less, equal or more strange than the objects in the second one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd translate the two sentences as

> Si tratta di oggetti **alquanto** strani
>   *We are talking about **rather** strange objects*

and

> Si tratta di oggetti **parecchio** strani
>   *We are talking about **very** strange objects*

So, **parecchio** is stronger than **alquanto** and it literally indicates a bigger quantity.

That being said, as a native speaker I would never use **alquanto** in a sentence, as it doesn't sound very colloquial. I'd go with **un po'**, which could be roughly translated to English as **a little**.

Answer (score 6):

From the [Accademia della Crusca explanation](http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/lingua-italiana/consulenza-linguistica/domande-risposte/avverbi-quantit):

> le forme *abbastanza, alquanto e piuttosto* risultano sinonimiche, in
>   quanto si definiscono reciprocamente.   La tendenza al rafforzamento
>   semantico si può inoltre notare nella forma *alquanto*, derivata dal
>   latino *aliquăntu(m)* che indicava una quantità discreta, spesso
>   traducibile in italiano con *un po'*. Il Dizionario Etimologico della
>   Lingua Italiana definisce infatti il valore avverbiale di questa forma
>   con «un poco», osservando nella sezione etimologica: «Alquanto nel
>   sign. di 'molto' è errore biasimato dal G. Gherardini, Voci italiane
>   ammissibili benché proscritte dall'elenco del sig. Bernardoni (Milano,
>   1812).   Considerando che il Grande dizionario italiano dell'uso
>   impiega il termine *parecchio* per definire questa forma avverbiale, è
>   quindi possibile ipotizzarne l'uso in senso intensivo, specie per
>   rafforzare un aggettivo (ad es.: "ti vedo alquanto stanco" =
>   'parecchio, molto stanco').

To sum up: The words *abbastanza, alquanto, parecchio, piuttosto* are synonyms and could be used to define each other. However, the etymology of *alquanto* (from the Latin word, meaning "un po' - few, a small quantity") makes it closer to *abbastanza* rather than to *tanto*.
At the same time, *parecchio* is usually defined as "a bit less than a lot":

> **Parecchio** C’è parecchia, anzi molta confusione intorno a questa voce. E quando si è detto *parecchia anzi molta* si è già spiegato tutto o quasi tutto. Al pari di *assai* (e non mettiamo nel mucchio altra roba come *abbastanza*, sennò facciamo soltanto confusione), *parecchio è meno di molto, equivale a piú che sufficiente, in quantità notevole, ma non è ancora molto* (Scrivendo e parlando di
>   Luciano Satta, Firenze, Sansoni, 1988, p. 177)

Answer (score 2):

The meaning overlaps out of a great deal, but *alquanto* would refer to a slightly smaller quantity with respect to *parecchio*.

So,

- **Alquanto + adjective** describes a value in the middle of the adjective, tending to it;
- **Parecchio + adjective** is a stronger assessment, which can be translated with "very + adjective".

Answer (score 2):

When used as adjective, *alquanto* could mean that something is less than *parecchio*, or it is equivalent to *parecchio*.

> Aveva bevuto alquanto vino.

As adverb, it means *parecchio, non poco*; as undefined pronoun, it means *un po'*.

> Oggi sto alquanto meglio.

> Con alquanto di buon vino e di confetto il riconfortò. —G. Boccaccio

Comment: In modern Italian I rarely heard alquanto used as an adjective.